# Run native code in background

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, native

I made an image processing application using OpenCV and Android NDK. Now, I want to display the result in my main activity which is the dashboard containing some data and graphs based on the native image processing application.

I look around and found that native code is only available to be run as activity (NativeActivity class), which is my approach currently where the main activity is replaced by blank screen of the native activity [reference#1](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/o9LxyoY5Rrk).

My questions are, is this true? How can I run my native code from the main activity while keeping the main activity active in foreground and the native code run in background?

Thanks guys!

Comment: I guess you can run your native code from Service also.

Comment: So worked? or any issue?

Comment: Hi @KanakSony, I tried your suggestion. I made a service, which basically calls the native activity (in the onHandleIntent). I still get error can't instantiate class com.example.ImageprocessService; no empty constructor

Comment: First, delete your constructor, as you inherit a public zero-argument constructor from Service.

Then, either make this be a static inner class, or make it be a standalone public Java class. You cannot use a regular inner class here, as Android has no way of creating an instance of that inner class.

Comment: Okay, I tried your suggestion and now it runs without error. But in the end, since the service still call the native activity ( startActivity(nativeIntent); ), the main activity is replaced by the native activity...

Comment: Why don't you just use JNI calls from your Java activity to your C++ functions if you don't want a native activity at all?

Comment: Thanks, I will look into your suggestion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I look around and found that native code is only available to be run as activity

No. Any Java class can have native methods in Android. You can have a background worker thread, implemented either as a `Thread`-derived class or as a `Runnable`, which would do the background work by calling native method(s).

pthreads are another possiblity, but those threads are invisible to the Java subsystem; you might want to call Java code from the worker thread - at the very least to pass something back to the UI thread. It's easier if the worker thread was started in Java in the first place.

For the record, Android services are not threads. They run on the main thread. Threads can be started from a service, but they can be started from an activity as well. Thread's lifetime is up to you.

The NativeActivity stuff is for having completely Java-less apps. You don't have to follow that way.

Comment: Hi, thanks Seva. So I guess, based on your answer and comment from user2359247 in my question above, I can design my app to execute the native code: in a background/worker thread by calling the native code using JNI?

Comment: You can. Absolutely. I use boost threads in my app with Java and C++ running side by side and everything is OK.

Comment: Yep, done it, thanks very much @user2359247. In the end I modify my native code, from android_app to pure C++ with JNI wrapper. All previous functions available to android_app (AAssetManager, ANativeWindow, etc) is moved to the Java part. Then I call the method as worker thread as Seva suggested. Thanks all!

Answer (score 2):

Android supports pthreads to a [large extent](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/android-platform/Cq05PaLaZbE). Feel free to use `pthread_create()` and her kin in your code.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your mind-opening suggestion. In the end I start the thread in the main Java class, instead of your suggestion because it seems fit with my current goal.